# mod_rewrite Multiple Variables

Tags: url, variables, mod-rewrite

Currently my url is `mysite.com/content` using:

```
RewriteRule ^page.php/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?a=b&content=$1 [L]
```

I'd like to have my url be `mysite.com/content/page` where both content and page are variables. I thought something like this could work, but obvious it is wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^page.php/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?a=b&content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^page.php/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?a=b&content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Try this and let me know if this is what you are trying to do.